# Can add-ins Communicate? Connecting Add-ins / Add-in Dependency

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

**Can Add-ins communicate?**

I have an Excel add in that communicates with an API. In that add-in it can take in the XML packaged data as a string and the route of the API as a URL/I as a string then POSTs it data:

```
Function PostApiXmlToXml(XML as String, URL as String) as String
   'Post to Url that XML data
   'PostApiXmlToXml = the XML response
End Function
```

The problem is that there are many different routes and functions needed. And not all users need/are authorized to use all Routes.

I either just give everyone access to every function but if they try to send to one they don't have access to it will respond with unauthorized.

**Or there is a way of having an add in for each function that Connects to the main communication add in?**

e.g. this separate add-in has a function that is dependent on the first:

```
Function CalculateSomething(x as double, y as double, z as double) as double
    Xml = "<x>" + x + "</x>" &_
           "<y>" + y + "</y>" &_
           ""  ""       "" "" 
    route = "www.api.com/api/controller/func"
    CalculateSomething = PostApiXmlToXml(xml,route)
End Function
```

Main problem is that users can opt in to new functions whenever they want, so I want to make it as easy as possible for the user to just download another add-in that will give them access. There's also many more functions to be added in the future.

Is it possible or am I going about this all the wrong way?

Would people recommend going down the VSTO route?(no experience in that whatsoever)

Comment: VBA doesn't use a `return` statement. Is this VBA, or something different language like VB.NET?

Comment: *if they try to send to one they don't have access to it will respond with unauthorized* -- will the **API return an error in this case** (i.e., an error result from the XML response?) or are you trying to control this solely through the Add-In?

Comment: The short answer is that Yes, Add-ins **can** communicate with one another (i.e., a function in Add_In_1 can call a function in Add_In_2, and using the Extensibility library you could probably even do some pretty tricky stuff, but realistically this looks like a problem for a managed code solution especially if you anticipate the need to add many more functions, routes, etc., in the future)

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes the XML will contain an error message and i have a custom function that splits the XML, If the xml contains the error it will return that as a string if not it will return the answer. 
Is there not a way of adding a reference to a specific add in at the top like 'using or Imports similar to the way in .net? or am i a dreamer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **is a way of having an add in for each function that Connects to the main communication add in?**

Assuming `CalculateSomething` is in one Add-In, and your other function `PostApiXmlToXml` is in Module1 of a separate Add-in (let's just call it "MainAddIn.xlam" which is already installed on the user's machine)

```
Function CalculateSomething(x as double, y as double, z as double) as double
    Xml = "<x>" + x + "</x>" &_
           "<y>" + y + "</y>" &_
           ""  ""       "" "" 
    route = "www.api.com/api/controller/func"
    CalculateSomething = _
        Application.Run("MainAddIn!Module1.PostApiXmlToXml", xml, route)
End Function
```

**Note** you need to specify the VBProject and Module by name in the `Run` statement.

To check whether the addin is installed you could use a function like this:

```
Function IsAddInInstalled(name$) As boolean
Dim a
Dim ret as Boolean
For each a in Application.AddIns
    if (a.Name = name) then
        ret = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If not ret Then MsgBox "Please install " & name
IsAddInInstalled = ret
End Function
```

Deciding *where* to call this function is another story. Of course you could call it within each procedure in your Dependent add-in, but probably it would be better to put it in the Workbook_Open procedure, just once:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call IsAddInInstalled("MainAddIn.xlam")
End Sub
```

This way, every time the user opens Excel, it will check for the availability of the "main" add-in, and raise a message box if it is not available.

Comment: Thank you very much, I assume i could just add an on error to this and "output please install MainAddIn.xlam", what sort of error handling/ response does it have?

Comment: You could do that except I'm not sure what would happen if error occurs in the MainAddIn, it seems probably better to do a check against the active Add-Ins instead (see additional helper function I added in the answer)